# Is the T-1000 hard to the touch? If so, why don't we hear it clanking around when walking on hard surfaces?

Tags: the-terminator-series

The T-1000 is made of a liquid metal alloy. We see the T-1000 using its properties to mimic humans, including their clothes, which means its clothes are made of liquid metal.

Does this mean it's hard to the touch and cold, just like metal would be? I find this particularly interesting when it mimics John's foster mother. She has long curly hair and is wearing soft clothes that drape over naturally. If these are all made of metal that means the T-1000 is adjusting tiny strands of metal individually in order to appear as a realistic human. That's a phenomenally complex task.

However maybe I'm over thinking it, and in such cases it simply chooses to wear a wig and real clothes.

In addition, I did some quick calculations and worked out the T-1000 would weigh about 490 kg if it were made of steel. I don't think we have any stats about the density of the liquid metal alloy, but comparing it to steel seems like a fair assumption to me. Even if it were more like titanium that's still 280 kg.

So if the T-1000 isn't wearing shoes and what looks like shoes are just metal, it seems to me when it's walking or running it would be making loud clanking noises with each step, which would make its presence pretty obvious.

Am I missing something or is this just an oversight?

Comment: While I don't have any evidence to supply this as an answer, we do see that the T-1000 is capable of changing the consistency of the material it's composed of at will (such as when it walks through the bars). It could quite simply keep the material forming the bottom of its feet slightly fluid, to act as a cushion while walking/running.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Liquids are slippery, so shouldn't T-1000 slip all the time?!

Comment: "Soft" things are the things that follow the shape of your "probe". Nano-machines of T-1000 perfectly capable to do so. And they probably can and will emit heat while functioning.

Comment: I said slightly fluid, as in not solid. More like rubber than steel.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Clearly if T-1000 is capable of being a liquid, then there is no reason why it should be hard enough to make clanking noises. It's trying to simulate a human, who are solid but aren't hard enough to clank.

Answer (score 2):

When the T-1000 mimics a substance, it does so perfectly **and with the same properties as that substance**. We see an example of this in a deleted scene from *T2: Judgement Day* when the glitchy T-1000 inadvertently mimics some plastic tape in the factory and its hand become plasticky and sticky.

That being said, we learn in [*Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator:_The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles) that the T-1000's skin is cold to the touch...

> **Catherine Weaver (T-1000):** *Come, sit on my lap.*
>   **Savannah Weaver:** *Your lap is cold.*
>   **Catherine Weaver:** *I know.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TSCC: Desert Cantos](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_215:_Desert_Cantos)</sup></sub>

...but her clothing and hair are sufficiently realistic to fool a seasoned detective given that he touches her repeatedly during their various encounters.

Comment: I have to take issue with using both the statement "When the T-1000 mimics a substance, it does so perfectly" and "the T-1000's skin is cold to the touch". I don't see how both can be true?

Comment: @IanNewson - It seems to be able to mimic things *at room temperature*. Skin at room temp feels cold.

Comment: But skin on a human is never at room temperature. We're earn blooded creatures.

Comment: I don't what the big deal about raising skin temperature to 98.6 -- this is just a minor release/upgrade. Customer service must get so many calls about this. I am pretty sure this problem will be licked very soon.